# i cant get this program to work correctly.

Tags: c

I have been asked to modify a program to read characters rather than numbers.
i modified the array into a char array. changed the two "%d" to "%c" as below

void main (void)
{

```
char a[100];
int counter;
int b;

counter = 0;

printf("please enter the length of the array:   ");
scanf("%d", &b );

while (counter != b)
{
    printf("please enter character:     ");
    scanf("%c", &a[counter]);
    counter++;
}

    a[counter] = '\0' ;
    counter = 0;

    while (a[counter] != '\0')
 {
printf("\n");
printf("%c",a[counter]);
counter++;
 }

 }
```

### when i run this the program does this:

please enter the length of the array:    (4)  
 
please enter character:     please enter character:   (a)  
 
please enter character:     please enter character:   (a)

a

a

---

() are used to indicate the user inputs.

would be really good if i could get some help.

Comment: Why are you asking for the length of the array?

Comment: the previous question wanted the user to define the size. this question just asks us to modify that code.

Comment: That's prone to failure. What if the user enters in 999? Then you will access an array location out of bounds.

Comment: `void main(void)` is wrong. `main` returs `int`.

Comment: Yeah, I know that if a user enters a number of 100 the program will break but the array size of 100 is what I was asked to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remember that [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) leaves the newline in the input buffer, so when you try to read a character it will that newline.

The solution is very simple: Tell `scanf` to read and discard leading whitespace, by adding a space in the format code:

```
scanf(" %c", &a[counter]);
/*     ^           */
/*     |           */
/* Note space here */
```

Comment: Thanks man. can't believe it was something that simple. well at least I'll always remember this now.